# Connect nearest neighbor point

Tags: r, lines, nearest-neighbor

I have a list of x-y coordinates for 30 data points (green dots in the pic) and I would like to connect them together.

[image: plot]

How can I do it in R? At the moment, I computed the distance matrix between each point by `dist()` to obtain the closest neighbor for each point. However this result in 30 edge pairs... sometimes multiple edges connect to the same point which is not I want :( How can I solve this problem in R?

```
  cities_num=10
  cor.matrix=matrix(0,nrow=cities_num,ncol=2)
  for (r in 1:cities_num){
  cor.matrix[r,]=c(sample(1:500, 1),sample(1:500, 1))}
  par(mar=c(4,4,2,4))
  plot(cor.matrix,pch=4,xlab="X coordinate",ylab="Y coordinate")
  centroid.x=mean(cor.matrix[,1])
  centroid.y=mean(cor.matrix[,2])
  bead_num=cities_num+20
  t=seq(0,pi*2,length=bead_num) 
  coords=t(rbind( centroid.x+sin(t)*10, centroid.y+cos(t)*10))
  for (point in 1:bead_num){
    symbols(x=coords[,1][point],y=coords[,2][point],circles=0.5,
            inches = FALSE, add = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide the format of the data so we could work with something?

Comment: Hi,I just included my code :) basically i want to be able to connect all symbols points together by lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a "symbol point" is and there seemed to be too many undefined objects in your code so I made my own set of "points". If just a regular point then use `polygon`:

```
 dat <- data.frame(s=sin(seq(pi,-pi,length=25)),
                    c=cos(seq(pi,-pi,length=25)) )
 png();
     plot(0,0, xlim=c(-1.5,1.5),ylim=c(-1.5,1.5) );
       with(dat, points(s,c));
       with(dat, polygon(s,c) ) 
 dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply. The xy coordinates for my points will move from time to time and it wont be a nice circle at the end. The reason why i use symbol() to plot  because there is a scatterplot underneath it (black dots in above figure). Would the polygon() still work in this scenario?

Comment: There's no reason the polygon needs to be regular polygon. It can be as irregular as you like. I thought you wanted the connections between the points and you already had success with `symbols`.